# Azure File system Application Quota not using entire App Service Plan Quota

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, quota

How do you configure how much of your app Service quota your app is using?

I want this app to use the entire app service quota but currently it is only using one fifth of the available quota.

Quota page screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this was some sort of  a cacheing issue in the azure portal.  i contacted support and they showed me a page which verified the actual limit was 50 like it was supposed to be.

If you are having this same problem, try pressing the refresh button on the page.  (NOT the browser refresh button)